# Angular material dialog not centered not preventing body scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have angular material dialogs in my app but unlike the examples on the angular material website, the dialogs don't render in the center of the screen and a bigger issue is that they allow background scrolling. This means the user can scroll on the backdrop and the dialog can at times disappear off the viewable window.

I've seen a number of examples around ScrollStrategy but none of these have worked. Shouldn't this behaviour 'just work' ootb?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue in a 'new' app

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/positioning-material-dialogs-438j

Comment: might you have some huge `z-index`es?

Comment: I was wondering about z-index, what effects does that hold on the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be hidden css applied to the body tag setting the position & overflow css. Once removed this works as expected from angular material.

Answer (score 0):

`MatDialog` ootb is shown in the center and with scrolling blocked. However they are using their `Overlay` service to show the `MatDialog`. The service creates a `div` with position set to `fixed` as last element in the body. In this `div` all the overlaid content, e.g. the `MatDialog`, is shown. However if you have created a new [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) in your document body positioning could be broken. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tce6sa?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) is a broken `MatDialog` where I've set `transform` to the body. Check if you have something similar in your styles.